# Check if a variable is of "async function" type

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

Given a variable, which is defined as follows:

```
const f = async function() {/* ... */};
```

How can I check if the variable `f` is of type `async function` ?

I already found this solution:

`f.constructor.name === "AsyncFunction";`

But the "f.constructor.name" is not compatible with IE11. Any other ideas ?

I know async functions does not work in IE11, ... but they work through babel compilation process. The idea is to find a way to detect async functions in an environment like node.js which would be compatible with IE11/babel for instance

Comment: Why do you need to do this? If your end goal is to be able to process both regular and promise-returning functions in the same way, `await Promise.resolve(f())` will do what you want.

Comment: This seems like a bad idea. There are functions that are not marked async but are still asynchronous and return a Promise. I would recommend you only perform introspection on the return type of a function.

Comment: If your problem is about compatibility, you can have another approach, like using some kind of [polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-polyfill). In React, for example, you can use [React Polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-app-polyfill) and get compatible from version IE9.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.
It looks like effectivelly, testing if a function is async is a bad idea, since with babel or other build tools, async functions are modified to be compatible with old browsers.
@DanPantry has the good approach i think. There should not be different treatment of a function or an async function, then there is no reason to test one over an other variable type.
Do you want to edit this comment as an answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a bad idea. There are plenty of functions out there that are effectively async (returning a Promise) but not flagged as such (perhaps they are transpiled down for browser support).

If you truly wanted to test if a function was async, it might be better to test if the return value has a `.then` property:

```
const maybeTask = f()
if ('then' in maybeTask) {
  maybeTask.then( .... )
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Instead of `f.constructor.name`, did you try `f().constructor.name`?

The former inspects f's constructor, whereas the latter will inspect the value returned by f().
If f is a async function, then `f().constructor.name` should return "Promise".

Not really sure if this is the best way to check for an async function, but thought it could help.

Comment: Which also means calling the function. That's a bad idea.